# Is there equivalent of Microsoft CMD DIR for SharePoint?

Tags: list, recursion, sharepoint, directory, filenames

How to List Recursively Elements of SharePoint URL? Similar to Microsoft CMD DIR command that list Folders and FileNames using Folder as Input.

For SharePoint, is there a Command or App that List Elements ? with following options:
1. Input: URL of Sharepoint
2. Output options: URL, FolderPath, Filenames, Recursive, Export to csv File

Thanks Ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I've done that in Python. Here's how to do it:

```
import os
folder = r'\\mycorp.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\NCICDXSCL'
result = [os.path.join(path, name) for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder) for name in files]
print(result)
```